# Adjusting the estimated mean of a sample, when the sample size changes

Tags: distributions, forecasting, prediction

Ok it is a bit difficult to describe in the title what I  want but the following description should be clear.

I have estimated (i.e. projected) that the mean of a yet unseen sample of datapoints is Μ. This assumes (i.e. my projection models assume) that there are, say, N=80 datapoints in the sample.

Now I find out that there are N=60 datapoints. But I cannot change my projection model which is already trained. Is there a way to take the projection M (which was made with the assumption that N=80) and adjust it for N=60. In other words. Would/Should the mean change?

Remember. I have an estimate of the mean of the sample and not the sample itself.

My impression is that, since the stochastic process that generated the data is stationary, then it shouldn't really matter what is the sample size. But maybe some uncertainty associated with the estimation of the sample mean.

Comment: What is the reason there are fewer datapoints? For instance, if someone selected the 60 lowest values out of the 80, certainly the mean would be reduced.  Even if the selection is random, is it independent of the process?

Comment: The random process (black box) produces a very weakly-correlated time series, and is for all intents and purposes stationary. The reason that there are fewer data points is that the process interrupted prematurely. So the last 20 points are gone.  Thus it is not random exclusion of 20 points.

Comment: Any nontrivial AR(1) process will supply an example where the conditional mean of the next 60 points differs from that of the next 80 points.  If, then, that is what your projection is attempting to estimate, and if it is doing a good job. then probably the estimate should change.  How much it should change will depend on how strong the correlations are among your data and those 80 points. The intuition is that stationarity does not imply there's no association between values at one time and another.

Comment: So basically there is no simple answer. At least any simple adjustment from the output side